# Allowing XSS on IIS 7

Tags: iis, xss

I have `a.domain.com` and `b.domain.com`, and would like to allow these to call javascript functions from each other.

`a.domain.com` has `b.domain.com` in an iframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `document.domain = "domain.com"` in javascript on both the HTML of a and b.